# R code to find a cumulative sum of a vector with a criteria set on another vector of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

```
p<-c(1, 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10)
q<-c("a",   "a",    "a",    "b",    "b",    "c",    "c",    "c",    "c",    "c")
r<-c(0, 1,  3,  0,  4,  0,  6,  13, 21, 30)
t<-data.frame(p,q,r)
```

In the above data I am trying to achieve vector r.
Vector r is a cumulative sum of vector p with a lag and a criteria set on vector q.
Please assume that dataframe is already sorted alphabetically using vector q

I have tried creating multiple vector with a lag and then trying to sum. but it isnt ideal.

Comment: I will be using this code on a very large dataset. so loop is not recommended.

Answer (score 4):

The most efficient method would be using `collapse`.

First create a `GRP` object.

```
library(collapse)
library(data.table)
setDT(t)
g <- GRP(t, by = "q")
```

Then do a grouped lag & cumulative sum using that `GRP` object.

```
t[, result := fcumsum(flag(p, g = g, fill = 0), g = g)][]
     p q  r result
 1:  1 a  0      0
 2:  2 a  1      1
 3:  3 a  3      3
 4:  4 b  0      0
 5:  5 b  4      4
 6:  6 c  0      0
 7:  7 c  6      6
 8:  8 c 13     13
 9:  9 c 21     21
10: 10 c 30     30
```

## `collapse` vs `data.table` benchmark

## 3 groups

```
mark(e1 = {
  g <- GRP(t, by = "q")
  t[, result := fcumsum(flag(p, g = g, fill = 0), g = g)][]
},
e2 = {
  t[, result := cumsum(shift(p, type = "lag", fill = 0)), by = q][]
}
)
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression    min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory     time       gc      
  <bch:expr> <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>     <list>     <list>  
1 e1          434us  484us     1905.    36.7KB     0      953     0      500ms <dt>   <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
2 e2          511us  548us     1646.    32.5KB     2.27   725     1      440ms <dt>   <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
```

## 10^7 rows, ~ 10^6 groups

```
t <- t[sample.int(.N, 10^7, T)]
t[, q := sample.int(10^6, 10^7, T)]

mark(e1 = {
  g <- GRP(t, by = "q")
  t[, result := fcumsum(flag(p, g = g, fill = 0), g = g)][]
},
e2 = {
  t[, result := cumsum(shift(p, type = "lag", fill = 0)), by = q][]
}
)
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory     time          
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>     <list>        
1 e1          694.9ms  694.9ms    1.44       244MB     0        1     0    694.9ms <dt>   <Rprofmem> <bench_tm [1]>
2 e2            21.3s    21.3s    0.0469      71MB     1.50     1    32      21.3s <dt>   <Rprofmem> <bench_tm [1]>
```

Answer (score 3):

**1)** This is a base R solution using `ave` and `cumsum`.

```
ave(p, q, FUN = cumsum) - p
##  [1]  0  1  3  0  4  0  6 13 21 30
```

**2)** This variation also works:

```
ave(p, q, FUN = function(x) c(0, head(cumsum(x), -1)))
```

**3)** The same idea can be used with the collapse package

```
library(collapse)

fcumsum(p, q) - p
##  [1]  0  1  3  0  4  0  6 13 21 30
```

Comment: Added solution (3).

Answer (score 2):

This will be quite fast:

```
library(dplyr)
t |>
  mutate(result = cumsum(lag(p, default = 0)), .by = q)
#     p q  r result
# 1   1 a  0      0
# 2   2 a  1      1
# 3   3 a  3      3
# 4   4 b  0      0
# 5   5 b  4      4
# 6   6 c  0      0
# 7   7 c  6      6
# 8   8 c 13     13
# 9   9 c 21     21
# 10 10 c 30     30
```

This will be even faster:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(t)[, result := cumsum(shift(p, type = "lag", fill = 0)), by = q]
```

Answer (score 1):

If we need good performance while keeping within dplyr, we can use `dtplyr`. dtplyr is a data.table frontend for dplyr.
It runs most of the code with data.table. Not all dplyr verbs and operations can be translated, but for simple use cases like this one, it works just fine.

```
library(dtplyr)

t <- lazy_dt(t)
t |> 
    group_by(q) |>
    mutate(result = cumsum(lag(p, default = 0))) |>
    as_tibble()

# A tibble: 10 × 4
       p q         r result
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1 a         0      0
 2     2 a         1      1
 3     3 a         3      3
 4     4 b         0      0
 5     5 b         4      4
 6     6 c         0      0
 7     7 c         6      6
 8     8 c        13     13
 9     9 c        21     21
10    10 c        30     30
```

Answer (score 0):

with `data.table` we can try

```
> setDT(t)[, rr := shift(cumsum(p), fill = 0), q][]
     p q  r rr
 1:  1 a  0  0
 2:  2 a  1  1
 3:  3 a  3  3
 4:  4 b  0  0
 5:  5 b  4  4
 6:  6 c  0  0
 7:  7 c  6  6
 8:  8 c 13 13
 9:  9 c 21 21
10: 10 c 30 30
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the question is stated that it could be assumed that the vectors are *already sorted* you can take the indices where there is a change in `q` and subtract this `cumsum` at those positions.

```
n <- length(q)
i <- 1 + which(q[-1] != q[-n])
r <- cumsum(p) - p
r <- r - rep(c(0, r[i]), diff(c(1, i, n+1)))
r
# [1]  0  1  3  0  4  0  6 13 21 30
```

A problem might be, that due to the fact that `cumsum` is build over the whole vector, its result might not be that accurate as it could be when splitting in groups. So another variant which is subsetting the vector.

```
n <- length(q)
i <- which(q[-1] != q[-n])
unlist(Map(\(i,j) {. <- p[i:j]; cumsum(.) -.}, c(1, i+1), c(i,n)), FALSE, FALSE)
# [1]  0  1  3  0  4  0  6 13 21 30
```

---

Benchmark

```
set.seed(42)
q <- rep(letters, sample(1e5:1e6, length(letters), TRUE))
length(q)
#[1] 13535111
p <- sample(as.numeric(1:10), length(q), TRUE)

library(collapse)
library(data.table)
t <- data.frame(p,q)

bench::mark(min_iterations = 7L,
collapse = {g <- GRP(t, by = "q")
 as.data.table(t)[, result := fcumsum(flag(p, g = g, fill = 0), g = g)][]$result},
Map = {n <- length(q)
 i <- which(q[-1] != q[-n])
 unlist(Map(\(i,j) {. <- p[i:j]; cumsum(.) -.}, c(1, i+1), c(i,n)), FALSE, FALSE)},
rep = {n <- length(q)
 i <- 1 + which(q[-1] != q[-n])
 r <- cumsum(p) - p
 r - rep(c(0, r[i]), diff(c(1, i, n+1)))},
ave = {ave(p, q, FUN = cumsum) - p} ) # @G. Grothendieck
```

Result

```
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 collapse   196.59ms 248.53ms     4.17      518MB     5.36     7     9
2 Map         539.4ms    568ms     1.78      981MB     3.80     7    15
3 rep        442.83ms 481.89ms     2.03      826MB     3.77     7    13
4 ave           1.18s    1.23s     0.801    1006MB     1.37     7    12
```

In this case using *collapse* with *data.table* is about two times faster than *base* Map and rev and 5 times than `ave`.